# Why was this question immediately protected without any previous activity?

Tags: support, protected-posts

The question ["Why does the Outlook PST repair tool always report that many errors?"](https://superuser.com/questions/798841/why-does-the-outlook-pst-repair-tool-always-report-that-many-errors) was protected 6 minutes after being asked. It did not receive any kind of reaction (comments, answers). Therefore, no spam either. Why was the question protected?

(I do not object to the protection. Just curious.)

Comment: The question is a good question, asking *why* the corruption or errors are occuring, but we get a rather large amount of "ost/pst repair" spam that latches on to any question that bears a vague relation to corruption in Outlook.  These usually appear from newly created (1 Rep accounts). As Bob mentions below we are a little sensitive about this and protecting your question is a good way to set a minimum bar to posting that will deter almost all spammers.  Sadly it does set a minimum bar for legitimate users too but it's really not that hard to get 10 rep here.

Comment: The amount of people without enough reputation to answer a protected question that would provide a quality answer can be counted with a single finger.  Questions are protected to prevent spam users from answering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We've had quite a few "PST repair" questions created by spammers as bait for their future spam answers. This protect was manually done by @slhck, likely as a preventative measure.